# Determining the properties of a button from its row and column tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a grid of buttons and then if you press one it moves but it is dependant of the text of the adjacent button, so if it is 0 it can move it if not it is stuck, and because the buttons move I do not know which button is pressed or is adjacent.

So, as i have the column and row of the button clicked, can i access the button name or text from the adjacent buttons based on the coordinates, essentially the opposite of .grid_info?

```py
def create_grid(event):
    side = int(math.sqrt(int(size.get())))
    for row in range(side):
        for col in range(side):
            button = Button(window, text = number, command=lambda row=row, col=col: move_box(row, col))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

Comment: but i need the text of the adjacent button

Comment: If you know `row/column`, read about [Grid.grid_slaves-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_slaves-method)

Comment: So will i have to create a master widget like a frame and then all the subsequent buttons within it to get the text?

Comment: ***"create a master widget"***: Yes, use a `Frame` as container.

Comment: But then is there a way to run if statements through the data, because I can change the text but I dont know how to access the text specifically.

Comment: so i have the widgets ```python widgets = numbts.grid_slaves(row, col)
                                      widgets[0].config(text="Button")
```
numbts is the frame, and so I can change the text on the button but cant go widgets['text] = because it is a list so I am not sure how to access it

Comment: This shows, how to set `text=`, the oposite is [Widget.cget-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method), e.g. `text = widgets[0].cget('text')`

Comment: Ok great thank you so much for your help!